# iOS - how to specify a callback from another class?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am an iOS newbie. I want to specify a success callback for an Http execution. However, that is in another class. How would I specify it? I tried the following -

```
[request setDidFinishSelector: @selector([[MyHttpCallbacks get] successHttpMethod]:)];
```

The callback functions are defined in the MyHttpCallbacks. This does not work. If I define the methods in the same class and use it like this it works fine -

```
[request setDidFinishSelector: @selector(successHttpMethod:)];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyHttpCallbacks *callbacks = [[MyHttpCallbacks alloc] init];
request.delegate = callbacks;
```

Comment: It is indeed as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I made the HTTP handling class (`ServerComm` in my case) to call a delegate method.

ServerComm.h I added at the end

```
@interface NSObject (ServerCommDelegate)
- (void)finishedLoading:(NSString*)result success:(BOOL)success;
@end
```

ServerComm.m

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    ...

    if ( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishedLoading:success:)] ) {
        [delegate finishedLoading:aStr success:YES];
    }    
}
```

In the main class after creating the instance

```
serverCommObj.delegate = self;
```

and then the method

```
- (void)finishedLoading:(NSString*)result success:(BOOL)success 
{
    if (!success) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe natively what you want to achieve is not possible (unless someone have a hack and I am unaware). I had this problem many times that I had to change my design and include the callback in the same class as where it is created.

Although, come to think of it. (This is a suggestion that I didn't try myself) You could have your callback class "include" in the main and then from there, call a selector function that calls the function inside the callback. Not a very efficient hack, but i think it will work.

So something like this:

```
[request setDidFinishSelector: @selector(callbackFunction)];
```

With the call back in the same class:

```
- (void)callbackFunction {
    [MyHttpCallbacks get] successHttpMethod];
}
```

Where successHttpMethod reside in another class and you include it as an import.